# GEE obtain bands from image collection

Tags: google-earth-engine

I'm currently working on my bachelor's thesis and I am trying to work with Sentinel 5 - P's aerosol data.
I am trying to obtain Aerosol Layer Height (L3__AER_LH) data but I do not know the bands, which I need to 'select'.

The README file on L3__AER_LH reads as follows:
The data file contains the aerosol_mid_pressure and aerosol_mid_height which provide the
air pressure at the center of the aerosol layer and the height at the center of the aerosol layer relative
to the geoid, respectively.
But when I try running: `.select('absorbing_aerosol_index');` I get no results.

Therefore, I have tried using `print(collection.bandNames);` but I recieve an 'undefined'.

Could someone help me obtain L3__AER_LH data from GEE?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hello Martí Prat! Your question is a little lacking and would need some clarification before anyone on this site could help you out. Check out ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to specify exactly which Earth Engine data set you are using, or if you uploaded it yourself? I did not find anything called `L2__AER_LH`, only [`L3_AER_LH`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S5P_NRTI_L3_AER_LH), in the public data catalog.

Comment: Thank you Kevin. Yes, I want to access the L3_AER_LH data, and with the provided link for [L3_AER_LH](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S5P_NRTI_L3_AER_LH) you have solved my problem! (I did not know the name of the band to select: ```.select('aerosol_height')```
Thank you very much!

Comment: All right, I've written an answer that covers both of those points. If that is satisfactory, please accept it with the checkmark button -- on Stack Overflow we don't want questions to only be answered in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Therefore, I have tried using print(collection.bandNames); but I recieve an 'undefined'.

The best way to find out about bands programmatically is to look at the band names of *one image*, because band information for a collection is sometimes incomplete.

```
print(collection.first().bandNames());
```

That said, for datasets from the Earth Engine Data Catalog, you'll get documentation as well as the names by looking at their catalog pages ([example](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S5P_NRTI_L3_AER_LH#bands)), so doing so is a better option in that case.

That page tells you that the band names for L3_AER_LH (as provided by Earth Engine) include `aerosol_pressure` and `aerosol_height`.

Comment: Thank you very Much!

Comment: Do you know why the presented data is 'scattered' and not consistent in different time intervals?

Comment: @MartíPratiEsquerdo Sorry, I don't. I recommend you post that question separately, to [GIS Stack Exchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/), so others who might know about that data set can see it.